# Python: ModuleNotFounderror: 'No module named image_downloader'

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, modulenotfounderror

Code that worked for months suddenly stopped working.

In a file in the same directory *'downloaders'*, I have an import '*import image_downloader'*. Somehow, the import doesn´t work anymore. The file that imports it is in the **same directory**.

My PyCharm IDE shows no problems at all, no warning or anything. But when I run it, the ModuleNotFoundError happens:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'image_downloader'**.

I have looked at similar questions here, but they haven´t helped me so far. I am desperate, and would be thankful for tips on resolving this annoying issue.

Comment: Show a screenshot of directory structure of downloaders (or even better text output of ls). sorry about format typing this on phone

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Not sure why it doesn´t work anymore with the old import style.

But what made it work: using **absolute imports**. This means in this case, instead of **import image_downloader**, I used **from downloaders import image_downloader**, *even when the importing file is also in the package image_downloader*.

Comment: This is not the only solution, however. To avoid absolute imports you can also use `from .image_downloader`